# Why directing output of command to a variable doesnt work in batch file

Tags: batch-file, scripting

I am trying to assign the output of the command `python --version` to a variable in batch script but it does not work.
Here is the sample code I am using

```
FOR /F "tokens=* USEBACKQ" %%F IN (`python --version`) DO (
SET message=%%F
)
ECHO %message%
```

Although it prints the version for python, it does not assign to the variable `var`.
If I use another command instead of `python --version` then the output is correctly assigned. e.g. using `dir` works.

What could be wrong?

NOTE -

```
@echo off 
set message=Hello

FOR /F "tokens=* USEBACKQ" %%F IN (`python --version`) DO (
SET message=%%F
)
ECHO %message%
PAUSE
```

OUTPUT -

```
C:\Users\nik>extra.bat
Python 2.7.9
Hello
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: In such cases, try to redirect the output to `NUL`, like `python --version > NUL`. If you can still see the version, the program doesn't output to stdout

Comment: Good idea, but I can't use `> NUL` redirection in the above code. Also, other command's output could be assigned to the variable except for `python --version`

Comment: @nik why not? any way without redirection your code works completely fine on my PC

Comment: @jeb tried on my PC, `python --version` does print to stdout

Comment: How can it output the version when the variable isn't defined? `echo %var%` is the only thing in your code that outputs to screen.

Comment: @Stephan  have updated the question with complete code.

Comment: @phuclv i have updated code for your reference

Comment: Try `python --version > test.txt` If you still see the output in the screen, then `python` doesn't send output to `stdout`; otherwise, you _should_ get in your `message` variable the contents of `test.txt`

Comment: @Aacini when i changed as you suggested, i get the error as `> was unexpected at this time.`

Comment: No. Open a command-line window and then, at the command prompt, just type: `python --version > test.txt` Don't run your .bat file!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The installed version of Python outputs obviously the version information to handle **STDERR** (standard error) instead of handle **STDOUT** (standard output). For that reason it is necessary to redirect the standard error stream with the version information to standard output stream using `2>&1` as described by Microsoft in the documentation about [Using command redirection operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490982(v=technet.10)).

The command line to use is:

```
for /F "delims=" %%I in ('python.exe --version 2^>^&1') do set "message=%%I"
```

The redirection operators `>` and `&` must be escaped with caret character `^` on **FOR** command line to be interpreted as literal characters when Windows command interpreter processes this command line before executing command **FOR**.

**FOR** respectively `cmd.exe` processing the batch file with this command line starts in background one more command process with `%ComSpec% /c` and the command line specified within `'` appended as additional arguments. Therefore is executed with Windows installed into `C:\Windows` in the background:

```
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c python.exe --version 2>&1
```

The command process in background searches now for an executable `python.exe` as described at [What is the reason for "X is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file"?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41461002/3074564) When the file `python.exe` could be found by `cmd.exe` running in background without a visible console window, it executes it and Python outputs the version information to standard error stream which is redirected to standard output stream of the background command process.

The started `cmd.exe` closes itself after `python.exe` terminated itself after printing the version information.

The `cmd.exe` instance processing the batch file captures everything written to handle **STDOUT** of started background command process and **FOR** processes the captured lines after started `cmd.exe` closed itself.

There is split up **by default** a non-empty captured line into substrings using normal space and horizontal tab as string delimiters. If the first substring after removal of 0 or more leading spaces/tabs starts with a semicolon, the captured line is ignored, otherwise the first substring is assigned to the specified loop variable `I`.

The default line handling behavior is not wanted here. For that reason the `for /F` option `delims=` defines an empty list of string delimiters to disable the line splitting behavior to get the entire captured line assigned to the specified loop variable `I`. The implicit default `eol=;` (semicolon is end of line) can be kept in this case as the version information output by Python starts never with a semicolon.